# Concatenation and MD5 with awk

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin, md5sum

I would like to concatenate all columns in a CSV file and then apply an MD5 hash.

I would like to use awk.

With this code, I get the concatenation of the third column.

```
awk -F'#' '{  { printf "%s",$3 } }'
```

and I can get the hash with this code

```
echo -n "HELLO WORLD" | md5sum
```

Can anyone help me to integrate those two methods? First concat all columns, then apply the MD5 hash.

Sample CSV:

```
A#B#C#D
E#F#G#H
I#J#K#L
```

The output will be:

```
 md5(ABCD)
md5(EFGH)
md5(IJKL)
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `echo -n "HELLO WORLD"` with your awk command? In what way does that not do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
here  my csv: 
A#B#C#D
E#F#G#H
I#J#K#L

The output will be:
 md5(ABCD)
md5(EFGH)
md5(IJKL)

Answer (score 1):

concatenating columns will mean removing the delimiter, here is a simpler approach

```
tr -d '#' <file | md5sum
```

if you want to extract the third column only and concatenate rows into one big string (but why since you're losing information)

```
cut -d# -f3 file | tr -d '\n' | md5sum
```

note that now these third columns

```
ab
c
```

and

```
a
bc
```

will end up with the same hash.  Better to preserve the distinctness of the fields by concatenating the values with the same delimiter

```
cut -d# -f3 file | paste -sd# | md5sum
```

however, without concatenation you can assume the fields are separated with the newline delimiter and go with

```
cut -d# -f3 file | md5sum
```

unless there is an unspecified reason.

**UPDATE:**  you want create md5 hash for each row! Which was the critical information missing in the question.

You can't pipe into md5sum the lines as in the other programs (you need a new invocation each time).  One way to address this is

```
tr -d '#' <file | while read line; do echo $line | md5sum; done

ed5d34c74e59d16bd6d5b3683db655c3  -
8ad37f51cbc6de792c885acf17ba7e40  -
fe672d984bef56cbfce488080f8055b7  -
```

however, note that you're losing information if your fields are varying in length and overlapping in values.

For example, `AB#C` and `A#BC` will generate the same hash, which may or may not be desired but I guess you might have not considered.

Comment: yes missed that, if so what's the purpose of the question though?

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of the question is. Hence no answer :-).

Comment: Thanks for this approach.
here sample my csv: 
A#B#C#D
E#F#G#H
I#J#K#L

The output will be:
 md5(ABCD)
md5(EFGH)
md5(IJKL)